# ctags generation from specific header file

Tags: vim, ctags

I have just started learning with STM32 microprocessors (C only) and I would like to generate `ctags` for vim-omniccpcomplete, but there is a little problem that the header file for this MCU is written like this:

`typedef struct 
    {
      int foo1;
      int foo2;
      int foo3;
    } RCC_Typedef;
    #define RCC_BASE (0x3800)  // direct place in memory (special function register...) 
    #define RCC ((RCC_TypeDef *) RCC_BASE)`

I would like to generate ctags so that I can use my vim for examples like this one:

```
RCC->foo1 = 3;
```

When I used

```
ctags -f ~/.vim/stm_ctags stm32f4xx.h
```

Generated ctags weren't generated well for vim to use them effectively.

*Thanks for help and I'm sorry for my English*

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Generated ctags weren't generated well for vim to use them effectively." What did you expect to happen, what commands did you run in Vim, and what actually happened?

Comment: This isn't an STM32 question, but a Vim/Ctags question - let's tidy up the tags.